# win32_process create fails with Unknown failure for service account user

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have a windows service account user, using which i'm trying to create a background process using the WMI win32_proces. But fails with Unknown Failure.
(Tried this with administrator, nonadmin, domain admin, domain nonadmin users. works fine)

```
 $process = [WMICLASS]"\\$computername\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process"
 $processinfo = $process.Create("powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden test.ps1")
 Write-Host $processinfo.returncode
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in this msdn blog post: [Win32_Process.Create fails if user profile is not loaded](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/04/09/win32-process-create-fails-if-user-profile-is-not-loaded.aspx), the WMI call is hardcoded to access the users profile through the registry.

If the user profile is not already loaded in **HKU**, WMI tries to load it into the registry using [`RegLoadKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889(VS.85).aspx).

This fails unless the user account in question have the following privileges on the local machine:

- **SeRestorePrivilege**
- **SeBackupPrivilege**

So, either

1. Grant these privileges to the account in question
2. Call [`LoadUserProfile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762281(VS.85).aspx) for the user in question prior to calling `Win32_Process.Create`
3. Or use `Start-Process` instead of WMI!

---

```
# Set up service account credentials
$Username = "domain\svcaccount"
$Password = "7oPs3çürEûN1c0deZ"
$Credential = New-Object pscredential -ArgumentList $Username,$(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)

# Establish a session on the remote machine
$RemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -Credential $Credential

# Launch the process with Start-Process -LoadUserProfile
Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession {
    Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -LoadUserProfile:$true -Argumentlist 'test.ps1' -WindowStyle Hidden 
}

# Cleanup
Remove-PSSession -Session $RemoteSession
Remove-Variable -Name Username,Password,Credential
```

Answer (score 0):

To Mathias suggestions in below comments:

Start-Process works in background only when invoked through interactive prompt. If run from a .ps1 script, the process created through start-process exits if the .ps1 script exits.

Inside your script. You can create a New-PSsession and then pass this session to invoke-command to trigger start-process.

But again to use New-PSsession and ExitPSSession, you must have Enable-PSRemoting and other setting enabled if you are lacking permissions. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/23/you-don-t-have-to-be-an-administrator-to-run-remote-powershell-commands.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What Mathias said on 2015 is correct with one small exception. If user profile does NOT exist then Create methods works even when profile is not loaded and user don't have SeRestorePrivilege/SeBackupPrivilege permissions. So simplest solution to this issue is create dedicated WMI service account which is not ever used to login to server.

I tested this behavior on all Windows Server version starting from 2008 and it looks to be same. Unknown Failure occurs immediately after profile is created and disappear when profile is removed.